# What causes a switch to reach the end of its lifetime?

Tags: switches

I am building a relay to measure the lifetimes of switches for different contact materials.

Almost every switch on the market will include information about it's lifetime (typically given in switching cycles). I think it is common for switches to last around 1 million cycles before they stop performing well.

This is where my uncertainty arises. What exactly affects the switches performance and how can I measure it?

For soft contact materials such as gold, the material will deform over time creating microscopic valleys and cracks. This would result in a higher switch impedance, correct?

So could I simply measure the initial impedance of a switch (given contact material a), then measure it once more and record the change in impedance after running the switch for 1 million cycles. Repeat the process for every material I want to test and which ever has the least percent difference would be the winner?

Comment: Not seeing the electrical engineering aspect of this question. Appears to be a mechanical engineering or materials topic.

Comment: Electrically speaking, switch life may also be affected by the amount of current running through the switch. Switches don't just "close" or "open", they bounce as the contact materials get near each other (as electricity arcs across them). These arcs can damage the contact material, or even weld them shut.

Comment: You are asking us to define the parameters. Usually, this comes from various customer requirements and gets baked into the testing/validation and/or quality control processes, both on the incoming supplier side materials used to make the switches and on the testing of the final assemblies. Different manufacturers will have different "big customers" who may drive some or all of this process, the rest of us getting the results of it. Who can say, totally abstractly, what kind of lifetime you want measured? Personally, I like "repairable lifetimes" because I repair things. Others throw them away.

Comment: @BrianCarlton: The question could be better but there is plenty of electrical engineering to this question as most of the wear will depend on the switching voltage and current. The relays will also be used in electrical applications.

Comment: related: [Is there any wearout mechanism for a relay simply from current flowing?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182001/is-there-any-wearout-mechanism-for-a-relay-simply-from-current-flowing)

Comment: Is this lifetime to include inductive loads?

Comment: fwiw, most of the worn-out switches i've encountered have worn out mechanically, not electrically. they are moving parts after all. i don't think resistance is telling: something can have good conductivity right up until the end. something can also be so over-built that it's lost a lot of surface (and thus conductivity) but still has thick contacts good for another 4m activations. i think physical actuating force is more predicative...

Answer (score 1):

In general, the long-term problem is degredation of the electrical contacts within the switch. This happens as a result of the two different types of actions which occur during operation.

1) Closing the switch. If the load has a large capacitance, there will be a large surge current through the contacts when they are closed. In the worst case, the contacts can be welded together, but even if that doesn't happen, the contact area can become pitted and unreliable.

2) Opening the switch. If the load has a large inductance, an arc will form as the load's magnetic field collapses. This will erode one contact, depending on polarity, and deposit material on the other. Eventually, the two contacts will become so damaged that the switch will fail to make contact.

And, just to complicate matters, it is necessary to specify the current levels which will be found in operation. The normal contact material in switches is silver. This has many good qualities, but silver is susceptible to corrosion, especially tarnishing due to traces of sulphur in the air. For large currents, silver contacts will usually show self-cleaning behavior as contact is made, but this may not occur at low currents - typically a couple of hundred milliamps or less. Switches intended for low-level operation usually have gold flashing on the contacts, which will not tarnish. However, such switches need special care. Specifically, they must not be used both for high and low level switching, since high currents will burn off the gold flashing, which is usually 100 microinch or less.

Comment: the switch to my hot water cylinder failed due to oxidation of the contacts,  the switch had been operated maybe ten times since it was new.  I suspect humidity traveling through the conduit (because of damp insulation on the cylinder) may have had some part in the failure.